# Qt5. How to load xsd schema from resources.qrc?

Tags: xml, qt, xsd, qt5

I want load xsd schema from my resources.qrc file. This part from *.qrc:

```
<qresource prefix="/xml">
    <file alias="my-custom.xsd">xml/my-custom.xsd</file>
</qresource>
```

This xsd is VALID (tested on W3C validator)!

I not want load this schema from local file. Because i want compile it as resource. My target: single executable file without other files and not required installation (just using *.so).

I look Qt (QXmlSchema) documentation and here we have 3 ways for loading:

```
bool load(const QUrl &source)
bool load(QIODevice *source, const QUrl &documentUri = QUrl())
bool load(const QByteArray &data, const QUrl &documentUri = QUrl())
```

I try:

```
QXmlSchema schema;
schema.load(QUrl(":/xml/my-custom.xsd"));
```

But it always invalid. I presume this is invalid value for QUrl. Or?

How to correct pass resource data in this loading method(s)? It possible?

UPD: Sorry for stupid question. It works:

```
QFile      schemaData(":/xml/my-custom.xsd");
QXmlSchema schema;
schemaData.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
schema.load(schemaData.readAll());
```